# Calculate sum of columns by their names

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider following data:

```
> df
   nt_1 NB1949j NB2021j NB3366j NB19491f NB2021f NB3366f nt_2
1     1       1       1       1        1       0       1    1
2     0       0       1       0        1       1       0    0
3     1       1       0       0        0       0       0    1
4     0       0       1       1        1       1       1    0
5     0       0       1       1        1       1       0    0
6     1       1       1       0        1       0       0    1
7     1       1       0       0        0       1       0    1
8     0       0       1       0        0       0       1    0
9     0       0       0       0        0       1       0    0
10   -1       1       1       1        1       1       1   -1
```

How to calculate following variables:

```
NB1949jf=NB1949j+NB1949f
NB2021jf=NB2021j+NB2021f
NB3366jf=NB3366j+NB3366f
```

I have **too many variables** that start with "NB" and end with "j" or "f". The names of variables is "NB"+ a unique code like 1949+ 'j' or 'f'. I want to sum of columns based on the unique code(like 1949).(It require to get the unique codes from dataframe col names)

```
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame(
  nt_1=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,-1),
  NB1949j=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1),
  NB2021j=c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1),
 NB3366j=c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1),
  NB1949f=c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1),
  NB2021f=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1),
  NB3366f=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1),
  nt_2=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,-1)
 )


NB1949jf=NB1949j+NB1949f
NB2021jf=NB2021j+NB2021f
NB3366jf=NB3366j+NB3366f
```

I think the first step to select the columns:

```
df2<-df %>% select(starts_with("NB") , ends_with("j") |ends_with("f"))
 df2
   NB1949j NB2021j NB3366j NB19491f NB2021f NB3366f
1        1       1       1        1       0       1
2        0       1       0        1       1       0
3        1       0       0        0       0       0
4        0       1       1        1       1       1
5        0       1       1        1       1       0
6        1       1       0        1       0       0
7        1       0       0        0       1       0
8        0       1       0        0       0       1
9        0       0       0        0       1       0
10       1       1       1        1       1       1
```

Now extract the unique codes as follows:

```
code1<-substr(names(df2),3,nchar(names(df2))-1)
```

Comment: `sapply(split.default(df[cols], sub('(j|f)$', '', cols)), rowSums)` where `cols` is `cols <- grep('^N.*(j|f)', names(df), value = TRUE)`

Comment: @RonakShah, How to force it to start with "NB" and end with (J|f)?

Comment: @RonakShah, I tried with '^NB.*\\.(j|f)$' but not working!

Comment: `cols <- grep('^NB.*(j|f)$', names(df), value = TRUE)` works for me using the data in the questions and returns 3 columns as output with `sapply(split.default(df[cols], sub('(j|f)$', '', cols)), rowSums)`

Comment: [{dplyrover}](https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover) can solve this kind of problems (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer). Here we could use `dplyover::across2`. This should solve the problem above `df %>% mutate(across2(starts_with("NB") & ends_with("j"), starts_with("NB") & ends_with("f"), ~ .x + .y, .names = "{pre}jf"))`.

Comment: @ TimTeaFan, this is exactly what I want!